# Ubuntu samba file server using ldap

Tags: 14.04, server, samba, openldap

I am quite new to samba. I have an ldap server already setup with users. I am now setting up a new samba file server that they will be accessing through the ldap. Has anyone done this before? I am trying to follow a few guides online but they are confusing. Could someone give me a link or a guide of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Evans, start here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-ldap.html

Both Samba and LDAP require solid beginnings. You really need to know what you want to achieve before going forward. They can be confusing topics.